# I'm getting errors on parse JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have this sample JSON code and I want to loop it through with jQuery AJAX but for some reason there is always error on console

this is the codes in file *new_content.json*

```
[
    {
        "name": "Mehmet",
        "email": "mehmet@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "Fareed",
        "email": "fareed3242@yahoo.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "Jonathan",
        "email": "jonathan@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

these are my html

```
<div id="main">This is the original text when page loads</div>

<button id="button1" type="button">Update content with Ajax</button>
```

this is inside javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button1").on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "new_content.json",
            success: function (rawData) {
                var data = JSON.parse(rawData);
                var result = '';
                result += '<table> \
                                 <tr> \
                                        <th>name</th> \
                                        <th>email</th> \
                                    </tr> \
                                    <tr>';
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    result += "<tr><td>" + item[i].name + "</td>";
                    result += "<td>" + item[i].email + "</td></tr>";
                });
                result += "</tr></table>";
                $("#main").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What's the error in the console?

Comment: rawData is already JSON, don't need to parse it, try to `console.log` it first

Comment: If the ajax method answer is application/json type then you don't need to parse it.

Comment: _"rawData is already JSON, don't need to parse it,"_ Eh? Do you mean it's already an _object_?

Comment: @KresimirPendic rawData is not a JSON, that's why no need to parse it.

Comment: To be more precise, your method is returning a Array of JSON objects, so you don't need to parse it, unless your array was formed by strings with json format, in that case you should parse every array elements.

Comment: Aside from the object perhaps already being an object without parsing, inside your each you are doing `item[i]`, but item is already the element at that index.  Take off the `[i]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes

1. First remove `JSON.parse()` you donot need to parse it.
2. iterating the data `item[i].name` is incorrect it should be `item.name` and `item.email`.

Apart from the 2 listed above you were missing the closing parenthesis of `.each` too if that was not a typo.

Run the following and everything will be fine i just confirmed it on my local machine

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#button1").on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "my.json",
                success: function (rawData) {
                    var data = rawData;

                    var result = '';
                    result +=
                        '<table> \
                                <tr> \
                                        <th>name</th> \
                                        <th>email</th> \
                                    </tr> \
                                    <tr>';
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        result += "<tr><td>" + item.name + "</td>";
                        result += "<td>" + item.email + "</td></tr>";
                    });
                    result += "</tr></table>";
                    $("#main").html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the inside of the each loop, you don't need to use `[i]` your loop should looks like :

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    result += "<tr><td>" + item.name + "</td>";
    result += "<td>" + item.email + "</td></tr>";
})
```

Code:

```js
var data = [{
    "name": "Mehmet",
    "email": "mehmet@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "Fareed",
    "email": "fareed3242@yahoo.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jonathan",
    "email": "jonathan@gmail.com"
  }
];
var result = "";

var result = '';
result += '<table><tr><th>name</th><th>email</th></tr><tr>';

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  result += "<tr><td>" + item.name + "</td>";
  result += "<td>" + item.email + "</td></tr>";
})

result += "</tr></table>";
$("#main").html(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:"new_content.json",
            success:function(rawData){
                        var data = JSON.parse(rawData);
                        var result = '';
                        result += '<table> \
                                <tr> \
                                        <th>name</th> \
                                        <th>email</th> \
                                    </tr> \
                                    <tr>';
                        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                                result += "<tr><td>" + item[i].name + "</td>";
                                result += "<td>" + item[i].email + "</td></tr>";
                        });
                        result += "</tr></table>";
                        $("#main").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Try this.